# Clearance Gem | Expire a Session after Closing the Browser in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, clearance

How do I automatically sign out when the user closes the browser ? Is there any configuration changes in clearance gem that would enable this.

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> Create A Cookie - Create or set a cookie on user machine having cookie
>   name, cookie value and the time when cookie should get deleted
>   automatically (EXPIRES atribute, this is optional). If this is not
>   specified the cookie is called a session cookie and it expires (gets
>   deleted) when user's session ends, i.e. when the browser is closed

[Source](http://www.technofundo.com/tech/js/jscookies.html)

In other words, if you don't set an expiration date on a cookie, it should "expire" when the browser is closed.

I've never used Clearance, but the [ReadMe](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance#configure) shows this configuration option in /config/initializers/clearance.rb:

```
Clearance.configure do |config|
  config.allow_sign_up = true
  config.cookie_domain = ".example.com"
  config.cookie_expiration = lambda { |cookies| 1.year.from_now.utc }
  config.cookie_name = "remember_token"
  config.cookie_path = "/"
  config.routes = true
  config.httponly = false
  config.mailer_sender = "reply@example.com"
  config.password_strategy = Clearance::PasswordStrategies::BCrypt
  config.redirect_url = "/"
  config.rotate_csrf_on_sign_in = false
  config.secure_cookie = false
  config.sign_in_guards = []
  config.user_model = User
end
```

If I were you, I'd attempt to set the cookie_expiration to nil. However, if it requires an expiration, you might want to fork the gem and see if the private API [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/blob/cf1f03c1fc045048306de84995cd3ed06675ed31/lib/clearance/session.rb) can be altered to your needs.

If you don't want to do that, you can create a guard in Clearance. When a user signs in, set your own cookie with no expiry date. When the user closes the browser, that should delete your custom cookie. Then, in your guard, when the authentication occurs again, you should be able to check for your custom cookie and (upon not finding it) reject the auth and redirect to sign_in.